# HighcharteR : unable to center x labels

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I tried a lot of thing to center x labels with columns without success.

Here is a reproductible code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(
  "sample"=c("sample 1","sample 2","sample 3","sample 4","sample 5","sample 6","sample 7","sample 8"),
  "sexe"=c("F","F","F","F","M","M","M","U"),
  "value"=c(12,14,8,10,8,6,5,12)
)

mybarplot <- df %>%
  hchart('column', hcaes(x = sample, y = value, group=sexe)) %>%
  hc_title(text="test column") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(pointWidth = 50))
```

The sample name are not centered with each column.

I tried lot of things :

hc_xAxis(labels=list(align="center"))

hc_plotOptions(column = list(pointWidth = 50, dataLabels = list(align="center")))

None of this line added individually in the code works.

Any clue ? Thanx

Comment: This should stack the bars of each group on top of each other rather than side by side. Now the labels should align with the center of your bar.
`hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))`.

Comment: @Fabrice Take a look at this example first and let us know if this is actually the view you are looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qm719szy/

If so, I can help you implement it in R

Comment: Thanx @madepiet but it's not what I was looking for